# error: cannot convert 'float*' to 'qreal* {aka double*} in initialization

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, mingw

I'm trying to compile old Qt project and i encounter this error:

> error: cannot convert 'float*' to 'qreal* {aka double*}' in
>   initialization

Here's the fragment of code:

```
void Camera::loadProjectionMatrix()
{
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
qreal *dataMat = projectionMatrix_.data();
GLfloat matriceArray[16];
for (int i= 0; i < 16; ++i)
    matriceArray[i] = dataMat[i];
glMultMatrixf(matriceArray);
}
```

What are my options to overcome this error?

Comment: What's the data type of projectionMatrix_.data()? If it's float then just use float instead of qreal.

Comment: @Archie [it's `float*`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmatrix4x4.html#data)

Comment: Well, then just use float :)

Comment: While `float` can implicitly be converted to `double`, the same can not be done for `float*`. A pointer to a type is very different from a pointer to another type, even if the base types are otherwise compatible. The problem with your code is that `float` is normally 32 bits while `double` is 64 bits, the offsets from the beginning of the array to any item except the first (at index zero) will not match for pointer to `float` and pointer to `double`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: yes, exactly.

Answer (score 5):

The projection matrix will return `float*` to you as per documentation:

> [float * QMatrix4x4::​data()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmatrix4x4.html#data)
>
> Returns a pointer to the raw data of this matrix.

The best practice would be to eliminate the `qreal` usage in your codebase regardless this case. When the contributors went through the Qt 5 refactoring, the qreal ancient concept was dropped as much as possible and definitely should not be used much in new code where the API deals with float.

The recommendation is to use float these days in such cases. This is a bit historical, really. Back then, it made sense to define qreal to double where available, but float where not, e.g. ARM platforms. See the old documentation:

> [typedef qreal](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qreal-typedef)
>
> Typedef for double on all platforms except for those using CPUs with ARM architectures. On ARM-based platforms, qreal is a typedef for float for performance reasons.

In Qt 5, the documentation is slightly different, although the main concept seems to have remained the same:

> [typedef qreal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qreal-typedef)
>
> Typedef for double unless Qt is configured with the -qreal float option.

I would fix your code the following way:

```
void Camera::loadProjectionMatrix()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    float *dataMat = projectionMatrix_.data();
    GLfloat matriceArray[16];
    for (int i= 0; i < 16; ++i)
        matriceArray[i] = dataMat[i];
    glMultMatrixf(matriceArray);
}
```

Strictly speaking, you could also go an alternative way to solve the issue, namely by using this method rather than `data()`:

> [float & QMatrix4x4::​operator()(int row, int column)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmatrix4x4.html#operator-28-29-2)
>
> Returns a reference to the element at position (row, column) in this matrix so that the element can be assigned to.

In which case, you could even eliminate the `dataMat` variable and assign the items directly to your `matriceArray` in the iteration.

Going even further than that, you should consider using a Qt library for this common task, namely e.g. the opengl classes either in `QtGui` or `Qt3D`. It would make more sense to mess with low-level opengl API calls if you do something custom.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, `projectionMatrix_.data()` returns a `float*`, and you cannot assign a `float*` to a `double*` (which is what `qreal*` is in this case).

Use

```
float *dataMat = projectionMatrix_.data();
```

or

```
auto dataMat = projectionMatrix_.data();
```

instead. The latter sometimes has the advantage that it might still be correct code if the return type of the function changes for some reason, although that is nothing to expect from a mature library. Additionally, you cannot get the type wrong on accident.

Comment: qreal is not actually double. It just sometimes is :)

Comment: How could the opengl API change in the foreseeable future? :)

Comment: @lpapp I don't know this API, the return type could depend on a define for all I know (that would be weird design though :) ). And the second reason stands regardless.

Comment: Not in the practical world, just in theory. Do you really think the opengl api will change?

Comment: @lpapp Nope, I do not really think that mature libraries just change like that. So if you want to write `float*`, just write `float*`. The change-safety reason applies more to projects in development. The main advantage here is the impossibility of getting the type wrong on accident.

Comment: `auto` would break it if .data() changed to double, no?

Comment: No, you would recompile after the API-change and auto would deduce the right type again (whatever that is then, and as long a the semantics of the type stay the same and you use auto every where, recompiling is all you need.)

Comment: No, not quite. The opengl API would expect float*, which would be the same problem again, just with auto! I cannot see how auto helps even in that case. The only case where auto could work if the Qt api _and_ the opengl change simultaneously and equally. That is like winning the lottery, isn't it and even then a simple float* to double* change would help. Also, auto would restrict the project to c++11 or later which is not a limitation for Qt.

Comment: Well, if an API change breaks compatibility, `auto` won't save you of course. It would break just as writing `float*`. I already wrote that it is completely fine to write `float*`, and if you cannot use  C++11, you cannot use `auto` (quite unsurprising :) ). I do not really get the point you are trying to make.

Comment: The point is clear: objectively, auto has only disadvantages here, so it is a bad idea to suggest it in this case. You said it could survive API changes, which is untrue. At least, you admitted that now, which is good because we are closer to the truth, although your answer is still wrong, respectively.

Comment: @lpapp I tried to clarify regarding the API-change. I still do not see a disadvantage of auto though.